# How to save persistent variable into .mat file?

Tags: matlab, persistent

I have a model of device which have internal state between calls.
Previously I passed that state in function call and returned a new state when exited from function.
Then, I found out about persistent variables which was exactly what I need. But problem is when I need to debug model or design between multiple calls it's hard to reproduce the exact call that I need.
For example, I have function foo:

```matlab
function [y] = foo(x)
    persistent k;
    if isempty(k) 
        k = 0; 
    end
    y = k*x;
    k = k+1; %% or even k = rand
end
```

I have multiple runs:

```matlab
x = 1:5;
for i = 1:5
    y = foo(x(i))
end
```

and have an error in 4'th call. Currently I need to run first three calls to get function state that actual for 4'th call (and if k was equal rand, I will not be able reach that state at all).
I tried to save workspace between calls to have an option to load all states but that doesn't work:

```matlab
for i = 1:3
    y = foo(x(i))
end
save foo3.mat
for i = 4:5
    y = foo(x(i))
end
clear all
load foo3.mat
foo(3)
```

> ans =
>
> ```
>  0
> ```

So how can I save that function state?
Actually, I can save that variable while function is run by putting save statement in code of function but for me that's seems not right. I think that statement should be at the top-script.

Comment: Can you replace the `persistent` variable by a variable that is passed to an returned from the function? `[y, k] = foo(x, k)`

Comment: Yeas, that's what I did before. I can use this method by I'm curious can I use persistent variables in my situation, because they works great until I need to debug.

Comment: For debugging, if you use `dbstop if error` you probably get the state of the function including the persistent variable, don't you? Anyway, to me (but then I don't know much about your use case) it sounds a bit strange that you want a persistent variable (that is, _hide_ the state withing the funciton) and yet you want to save the state (to _access_ that state from the outside)

Comment: By error I mean miscompare results of model and design, thats error is generated by another tool, not matlab, so `dbstop if error` will not occure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the most appropriate solution to my question is replace persistent variable by global one. In that case I have minimum changes to original code:

```matlab
function [y] = foo(x)
    global k;
    if isempty(k) 
        k = 0; 
    end
    y = k*x;
    k = k+1; %% or even k = rand
end
```

And debugging like:

```matlab
x = 1:5;
for i = 1:3
    y = foo(x(i))
end
global k;
save("foo3.mat","k")
clear all
load foo3.mat
foo(4)
```

The best solution I found is to create class-based model and move variables that stores state into class property. I can save class-object like any other variable so I can save any intermediate state of model:

```matlab
classdef foo < handle
    properties(Access = private)
       k; 
    end
    methods
        function self = foo()
            self.k = 0;
        end
        function [y] = bar(self, x)
            y = self.k*x;
            self.k = self.k+1; %% or even k = rand
        end
    end
end
```

And debug like:

```matlab
f = foo();
x = 1:5;
for i = 1:3
    y = f.bar(x(i))
end
save bar3.mat
for i = 4:5
    y = f.bar(x(i))
end
clear f
load bar3.mat
f.bar(4)
```

In that case I don't need to pass and return states and I can load any inermediate state.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

**clear**
Dont use 'clear all'.   You rarely if ever need to do `clear all`, a simple `clear` is usually sufficient.

**mlock**
Put [mlock](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlock.html) in your function, note this has other implications which you should understand by looking at the documentation.  Primarily you have to unlock ([munlock](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/munlock.html)) it to edit the function file.

Note this will keep your persistent variable for the matlab session only.

```
function [y] = foo(x)
    persistent k;
    mlock;
    if isempty(k) 
        k = 0; 
    end
    y = k*x;
    k = k+1; %% or even k = rand
end
```

Comment: Clear all is needed in order to completely clear the workspace, including persistent variables of all functions. I could use `clear foo` of course.

Comment: Use `mlock` in that case - as `clear all` wont clear any function which is locked.

Comment: Actually, I don't see, how mlock will help with my problem. It will keep the last state when I need to get intermediate state. Currently I think about writing a class-based model and saving the class object between the calls.

Comment: I saved last state in the example just to show that `save` fun will not help with saving persistent variables and that exmaple is more simple than splitted one which have save-statement between calls.

Comment: I interpreted your problem (probably incorrectly) as an a problem that you were clearing a persistent variable with `clear all`.  If you need to interrogate intermediate values you need to store them somewhere - maybe output them to an array?

Comment: That was how I did it early before found out about persistent variables. But this seems like ugly. I thought there is solution to save persistent variable 'cause that would be best for this case.

Comment: The persistent variable can be an array/matrix